# Is Trello code re-used to power the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, live-refresh

Just curious hoping a Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange programmer can answer.  Saw the recent changes with Stack Overflow where nice updates are made to the "Answered in X minutes" where X changes dynamically (nice job btw).

I was wondering since Joel owns Fog Creek, and they wrote Trello do the developers from both teams share common code etc?  Because I've seen Trello has this type of UI was wondering if you guys all just use common code or help with specific tasks / issues.

Comment: IIRC they do eat together, so I imagine they pass round their knowledge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do eat lunch together, and we do talk about what we're doing and what problems we're having, but the code is completely separate (I'm on the Trello team).

Comment: Stack Exchange dev confirming, Trello is CoffeeScript and Mongo (iirc); Stack Exchange is .NET, SQL Server, and Redis.  Not much code sharing to be done there, so just knowledge exchange.